# Add font awesome icon to Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I using .net core and in view page I need to add icon to ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Address", "AddAddressTempItem", "Leads", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new
                                           {
                                               @data_ajax = "true",
                                               @data_ajax_method = "Get",
                                               @data_ajax_update = "#AddNewAddressInformationModalDiv",
                                               @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",
                                               @data_ajax_success = "OpenAddAddressTempItemOnSuccess",
                                           })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add New Address", "AddAddressTempItem", "Leads", null, new
{
    @class = "btn btn-primary",
    @data_ajax = "true",
    @data_ajax_method = "Get",
    @data_ajax_update = "#AddNewAddressInformationModalDiv",
    @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",
    @data_ajax_success = "OpenAddAddressTempItemOnSuccess",
})
```

result:

[image]

[image]

Also,you can remove `@` before `data-xxx` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Address", "AddAddressTempItem", "Leads", null, new
{
    @class = "btn btn-primary",
    data_ajax = "true",
    data_ajax_method = "Get",
    data_ajax_update = "#AddNewAddressInformationModalDiv",
    data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",
    data_ajax_success = "OpenAddAddressTempItemOnSuccess",
})
```